# How is the standard normal distribution different from other normal distributions?

Tags: self-study, distributions, normal-distribution

In which of the following ways is the standard normal distribution different from other normal distributions?

Select one:

A. The mean ($\mu$)
of the distribution.

B. The standard deviation ($\sigma$) of the distribution.

C. The unit of measurement of the distribution.

D. All answer choices are correct.

Comment: Please tag this with the [tag:self-study] tag and tell us what you have tried and why so that people can offer useful hints.

Comment: I'm choosing D. It's definitely A and B, but I'm confused by C.

Comment: @Annie I'm confused by (C) as well. What is "the unit of measurement" of a distribution?! Are they trying to refer to sufficient statistics? Or is it just meaningless mumbo jumbo?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is the question I was given and because I think both A and B apply, the answer has to be D?

Comment: @Annie That's what I would do, but I understand your confusion with (c). Sometimes people write bizarre stuff. I'd move on and not worry about it.

Answer (score 7):

The normal distribution is fully characterized by its mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Probability distributions do not have "units of measurement." So the answer is A, B, and "this question is poorly written."

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. The mean and standard deviation may have units - the units of the measurement. Therefore, the PDF has units of inverse standard deviation. Whereas the standard normal distribution is normalised to zero mean and unit variance, so the measurement units are normalised out - see my answer below. I think that's what the question is trying to get the student to understand - although I agree that it's not very well written.

Comment: It is not meaningful to assign units to the density - this is a nonnegative $L^1$ function normalized to have integral $1$. Its value can be changed at (countably) infinitely many points to zero or to $+\infty$ without altering the distribution.

The random variable itself, however, may be interpreted in terms of units (e.g. $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is the length of a pencil). But changing $\mu$ and/or $\sigma^2$ does not change the underlying units of measurement, which would be e.g. meters for the mean and meters squared for the variance.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm (and I think the original question) is trying to get at - albeit poorly. Many stats programs let you construct a histogram or frequency plot that does not have unit area - unless you specify that option - and call them "distributions" even when not plotting density. And if you look at the PDF function - it appears to give units of inverse measurement, regardless of whether you normalise to 1 or any of the other infinitely many points. I'd think the question is trying to get to this point, in a course that obviously can't use mathematical terminology as you have.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing what they refer to as units in C is the unit of measurement of whatever is being measured.

In other words, if you calculated a normal distribution for peoples' heights, the x would be measured in units of, for example, cm.

If you then scaled and translated your results to give a mean of zero and sd of 1 (so you converted it into a standard normal distribution) then you'd effectively normalise out the units of x. (Scaled) Principle Component Analysis sort of does that.

So, as you say in one of your comments, A and B force C, so the answer is D. I don't think there's a more subtle statistical answer.